# Spring Boot Store HashMap To DB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have following input payload:

```
 "sources":{
             "kafka": {"clusterName": "dev", "topics": "topic"}
         
         },

"notification": {
            "slack": "alerts",
            "email": {
                "emailTo": [
                    "person@mail.com",
                    "person2@mail.com"
                ]
            }
        }
```

My Entity Classs is as follow :

```
@Entity
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
public class Details
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    /
       ..... other fileds

    /

    private HashMap<String, Object> notification;

    private HashMap<String, Object> sources;


}
```

In DB side I am seeing it's storing it as a bytea datatype, Is this a good practise to store it in this format ?  Is there any better way to store this type of fields ?

Comment: I would say your question is very opinion based but here is a good article https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-persisting-maps

Answer (score 1):

You might want to define the `Details` entity more concisely. As well as altering the mapped table for that entity in the database. For example, you might want to create other entities for sub-keys in the json. Or, just simple   new fields.

For a more scalable approach, define a Relational database by creating simple crud tables with their relationship with entities.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, its more a comment.